# Using tab control in a tab (Material skin2) in C# .NET 5

Tags: c#, material-design, visual-studio-2019

I have created a windows form application in Visual Studio 2019.
I use MaterialSkin.2 for designing. I use material tab control as a root menu to separate the functions. Each tab has a sub material tab control as a sub menu but my problem is never show the sub material tab control at all. I can't see the reason why.

**Update**:
I tried with .NET 4 as well but the same behavior. I think it is a bug

I try to follow this way but here there is on a root material tab control.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEtXGyn8OMA&ab_channel=FoxLearn

Could you help how can I show the sub material tab control under a tab please?

Answer (score 1):

Place a control called Material Tab Selector right above the Material tab control.
If you look at the Material Tab Selector property, there will be a BaseTabControl at the second from the top.
Just set it to the tap control you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).